# Adding application doesn't proceed

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

there.

i will try to make a new application.
then i did it which is based on this page.
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install

But I can't add an application yet.
because the process of adding application suddenly stop.

I did this procedure on 'Add a Run Script Build Phase'.
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install?step=1

[image]

but mac fabric app didn't proceed next step.
so that i couldn't add a new application yet.

my environment is Xcode 10 on Mac OS Mojave.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to support.then this problem was solved.